# jQuery AJAX JSON data is flattened

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

When I try to send a nested object to my server using `$.ajax()`, the data received by the backend is flattened. I need to be able to send an object that contains another object to my backend. Here's an example of what's happening:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/users/create'
  data: {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 42,
    marbles: {
      blue: 4,
      red: 8
    }
  }
})
```

```
{
  'name': 'John Doe',
  'age': '42',
  'marbles[blue]': '4',
  'marbles[red]': '8'
}
```

I am expecting the following:

```
{
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 42,
  marbles: {
    blue: 4,
    red: 8
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue what I can do to fix this? I have tried adding `dataType: 'json'` to the AJAX request.

Comment: It is being sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is exact same as if it were a regular form submit. What are you expecting in back end?

Comment: @charlietfl check my edit

Comment: ok... any back end language that processes form posts would process what is sent. Forms default hasn't changed for many many years. Can certainly use json...but what you have already can also be easily managed

Answer (score 2):

You need to stringify your object first.

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/users/create',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 42,
    marbles: {
      blue: 4,
      red: 8
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: And then parse it on the backend? This seems a little bit hacky to me. Is there any way to do it without doing this?

Comment: It's not hacky, it's essential to encode a complex object before sending it down the wire. If you don't, you get the problems you've seen.

Comment: Have to set `contentType` also doing it this way

Comment: I agree with @Will --  When using complicated data sets sending JSON through and parsing it on the other side is your best bet.  Your data will maintain it's integrity this way.

Comment: If u dont want to stringify the object you can use $.post(url,{
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 42,
    marbles: {
      blue: 4,
      red: 8
    }, "json");